# Отобразить на странице элементы в цикле

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

Всем привет, на работе нужно сделать простое задание - вывести таблицу, в итоге в контролере написал функцию, которая запросит файлик с локального сервера (файл меняется постоянно), и распарсит его на нужные поля, создал страницу где надо вывести поля по колонкам пока там есть элементы, звучит просто, но никак не могу понять как сделать цикл

```
while x < @myelement.count-1 do
x += 1
<td>myelement[x]</td>
end
```

Comment: Так. А страница будет чем генерироваться? Ванильным руби или какой-то шаблонизатор? Куда сохраняются данные между этапами "распарсить файл" и "показать пользователю"?
В общем, хотелось бы больше подробностей по требованиям к архитектуре.

Comment: да требований почти нет, это просто элементарная таблица на 1 страницу, которая доступна только с внутренних ресурсов, данные в этот момент хранятся в переменной, срок действия файла всего 5минут, нету смысла хранить где то еще

Answer (score 3):

ответ был достаточно простым, что бы выполнить руби код, достаточно написать

```
<ul>
  <% @show_all.each do |r| %>
     <tr>
     <td><%= r['name'] %></td>
     <td><%= r['ttl'] %></td>
     <td><%= r['type'] %></td>
     <td><%= r['value'] %></td>
     </tr>
  <% end -%>
</ul>
```

Comment: Там это, минус лишний в конце .-.